# How to add an API to API Publisher in API Manager Component in WSO2 using CURL with 1.6.0

Tags: java, api, curl, wso2, curl-commandline

When I'm executing a curl request to publish an api in API Manager-Publisher it shows it is added ... but not able to change its status.. !!!  Not able to open that API as well !!!

My Request:

```
curl -X POST -b cookies  http://my.api-site.com:9763/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag \
 -d "action=addAPI&name=TwitterAPI&context=/twitter&version=1.0.0&tier=Bronze&tier=Gold&transports=http&http_checked=http&transports=https&https_checked=https&description=Twitter&visibility=public API&tags=twitter,api&resourceCount=0&resourceMethod-0=GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS&resourceMethodAuthType-0=Application & Application User,Application & Application User,Application & Application User,Application & Application User,None&uriTemplate-0=/*&resourceMethodThrottlingTier-0=Unlimited, Unlimited, Unlimited, Unlimited, Unlimited&tiersCollection=Bronze,Gold,Silver,Unlimited" \
 -d 'endpoint_config={"production_endpoints":{"url":"http://search.twitter.com","config":null},"endpoint_type":"http"}'
```

Responce:

```
{"error" : true, "message" : " null"}
```

Can anyone help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters are passed in curl as `key1=value1&key2=value2...` format. So, if the key1, key2, value1, value2 contains any special character like `=`, `&`, `?` then should be urlencoded.

Your problem is with this parameter:

```
resourceMethodAuthType-0=Application & Application User,Application & Application User,Application & Application User,Application & Application User,None
```

You have lots of `&` character in your value. It should be `urlencoded`. For example this & should be replaced with `%26` So the string will be:

```
resourceMethodAuthType-0=Application %26 Application User,Application %26 Application User,Application %26 Application User,Application %26 Application User,None
```

Another thing, if you are running the command from windows, the use double quotes always, not single quote. For example:

```
-d "endpoint_config={\"production_endpoints\"...}"
```